# How do I restructure a data structure with dynamic sizes?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a data structure that needs to be read, parsed, and partially duplicated.

The incoming structure starts out in the form of an arbitrary number of lists and an index buffer. Each element in the index buffer contains one index for each of the lists. These structures are stored back-to-back in the same file.

For example:

lists:

list 1: 0x4325, 0x5356, 0x634f, 0xe534, 0x6324 
list 2: 0x4393, 0x0432, 0x2435, 0xa34e, 0xfae3 
list 3: 0x5235, 0x4583, 0x5355, 0x4325, 0xfeea

index buffer:
item 1: 0, 4, 2 
item 2: 0, 4, 4 
item 3: 0, 4, 2 
item 4: 2, 3, 1

Each item in the index buffer holds three indexes, which indicates which element of the corresponding list it is referencing. The first index references a value in the first list, the second index is for the second list, and the third index is for the third list.

I want to restructure the data so that each item only requires one index. The new structure would look like this:

lists:
list 1: 0x4325, 0xfae3, 0x5355
list 2: 0x4325, 0xfae3, 0xfeea
list 3: 0x634f, 0xa34e, 0x4583

index buffer:
item 1: 0
item 2: 1
item 3: 0
item 4: 2

each item in the index buffer now represents a full list, instead of an element from a list.

This would be fairly straight forward, except that I don't know at runtime how many lists there are, how many index buffers there are, or how many items there are. It's all specified in the file.

Also keep in mind that while in this specific example I save some space, I expect to be dealing with an index buffer that is thousands of elements long, so it will actually take up more space after the transition (which is okay)

Comment: How are data arranged in the source file. Is it one file with lists and one with index buffers? Or one common file? Is "list 1:" or "item 1:" part of the source file? By using a vector, it seems to be fairly simple. Can you add this information please? Thank you

Comment: @ArminMontigny I added that info, they are stored back to back in the same file. Using a vector won't work because the structure of each element (and by effect the number of index buffers) is also specified in the file, and you can't create a struct with custom elements at runtime

Comment: I would be happy to help you, but I still do not understand the format of the data in the file. Can you please paste a small example source text file?

Comment: It is based on this: https://wiki.axiodl.com/w/index.php?title=Geometry_(Metroid_Prime)

Comment: I left out the link because I wanted the question to be more generally applicable